# golang what is the right way to use math.max on two uint values?

Tags: go

This is what I do, it is extremely ugly.

What is the right way to use `math.Max` for 2 uint s?

```
vs.curView.Viewnum =uint(math.Max(float64(args.Viewnum+1), float64(vs.curView.Viewnum)))
```

Comment: unfortunately you'd have to write your own version for uints as far as I'm concerned

Comment: [Don't abuse math.Max / math.Min](https://mrekucci.blogspot.com/2015/07/dont-abuse-mathmax-mathmin.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main reason `math.Max` exists is to ensure some of the special cases of IEEE floating point are handled correctly (positive and negative infinity, `NaN` and signed zeroes).

These issues are not relevant for simple integers, so you may as well just use the obvious implementation.  Something like:

```
if args.Viewnum+1 > vs.curView.Viewnum {
    vs.curView.Viewnum = args.Viewnum+1
}
```

Comment: really stupid design about this. A generic max() function is not a luxury to have.....in my opinion. anyway. Thanks James.

Comment: Well when Go gets some form of generics, perhaps we'll see one.

Comment: It's a shame that Golang as a MODERN programelanguage doesn't support generics.

Comment: i think go is overall well designed but it is not mature, as we can see with simple expressions like this needing boilerplate

Comment: @mukunda: well, Go has generics now, so it's possible we'll see more utilities like this in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, maybe [this package](https://github.com/adam-lavrik/go-imath)  will save someone's time and efforts. It is obtainable via `go get` and importing by URL, as usual.

Usage:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "<Full URL>/go-imath/ix" // Functions for int type
)
...
fmt.Println(ix.Max(100, 152)) // Output: 152
fmt.Println(ix.Maxs(234, 55, 180)) // Output: 234
fmt.Println(ix.MaxSlice([]int{2, 29, 8, -1})) // Output: 29
```